# The preloadedState argument passed to createStore has unexpected type of "Array". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to add `createStore` to my project I am getting this warning. I don't know Why. I really want to remove this warning .

> The preloadedState argument passed to createStore has unexpected type of "Array". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys

Any Help would be great.

This is my store.js

```
const middleware = [thunk];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  middleware.push(createLogger());
}

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);
```

Comment: Middleware is the 3rd argument to [createStore](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore), maybe try to pass undefined as second argument: `createStore(rootReducer,undefined,middleWare)`

Comment: still having same issue

Comment: Do you have a sandbox, git project or snippet that can demonstrate this problem?

Comment: @adityakumar, have you fixed this problem? I am getting the exact same warning and this is what the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) says about the second argument to `createStore`:  `this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it`. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I did solve this issue  i just forgot to update the question. Can you check your rootReducer . I guess this is related to reducer i don't remember exactly .